# Issues with fgets and printf..printing a string

Tags: c, printf, fgets

working on a c project and I've hit a roadblock. I'm trying to print the point coordinate style, and I've included all the code necessary to help you folks help me out!

```
//point.h
struct Point{
   char label;
   int x;
   int y;
};

//point.c
displayPoint(struct Point p){
   char label = p.label;
   int x = p.x;
   int y = p.y;

   // label: (x, y)
   printf("(%c: (%d, %d)", label, x, y);
 }


 //build point from standard input
 readPoint(){
    struct Point point;
    printf("Enter label (character): ");
    fgets(buff, MAX_LINE, stdin);
    point.label = buff; //I think this is the issue here
    printf("Enter x:");
    fgets(buff, MAX_LINE, stdin);
    point.x = (int) strtol(buff, NULL, MAX_LINE);
    printf("Enter y:");
    fgets(buff, MAX_LINE, stdin);
    point.y = (int) strtol(buff, NULL, MAX_LINE);
```

Upon compilation, I receive the following error:

```
points.c: In function 'displayPoint':
points.c: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
points.c: warning: format '%c' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has   type 'char *' [-Wformat]
points.c: In function 'readPoint':
points.c: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
```

If I create a Point using the following information:

```
Label: A
x: 2
y: 3
```

and run displayPoint I get this output:

```
R: (2, 3)
```

Obviously that's wrong, I don't know where the R came from. What am I missing here? Why does C have to be so stubborn, this would be so simple to do in java, python, etc

Comment: C has an additional concept of pointers, which gives people headaches. But without it, concept of programming is some what incomplete though it is equally dangerous and would take time to learn. As already pointed out, you are trying to assign a char array (buff) to a single char which is not possible.

Comment: This: `readPoint(){ /* ... */ }` is an obsolescent form of function definition, and it won't even compile with a C99 or later compiler. Always declare the return type and all parameter types explicitly; if a function has no parameters, use `(void)`. So that should be `void readPoint(void) { /* ... */ }`. Similarly for some of your other functions. (This isn't the cause of your problem.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a couple of problems here:

1. `fgets` gets a buffer, not a single character.  I hope `buff` is declared as a character array (`char buff[MAX_LINE]`).
2. Your struct declares a single character for its label, but you're assigning your buffer to the character.
3. You're reusing the buffer.  Because this is just a pointer to a chunk of memory, you're potentially clobbering old data.  You might (read, probably will want to) reset your buffer between uses.

Given this, I think what you intend is this:

```
point.label = buff[0];
```

I'm guessing you just want a single character for your label, in which case this should work and you won't be clobbering that value.  (I don't know about the rest of your input.)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot perform such asignment:

```
point.label = buff;
```

buff is an array and label is a character. You may use memcopy but if you need a label in your struct put an array there so that you can store it there. In a character you may store 1 character only.

Answer (score 1):

```
 point.label = buff //I think this is the issue here
```

Do you see a semi-colon on the end of that line?
Don't C statement end with semi-colons?

---

Same here:

```
struct Point{
   char label;
   int x;
   int y;
}
```

Struct declarations should end with a semi-colon.

Comment: Woops, missed that one, there's one in my code just not in the code I wrote in here. I like to rewrite my code when I ask questions, helps me to find my own bugs sometimes! Thanks

Comment: @NesBa: Rewriting your code before posting here is fine, but do it on your own system, and copy-and-paste the *exact* code that you've fed to the compiler. We can't tell the difference between errors that are actually in your code and typos you made while posting it. Don't make us guess.